# Does AllowAnonymous override AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to stop a particular user in a particular role(say RoleA) from accessing a particular action. Anonymous users are allowed to access, but a user in RoleA is not allowed to access the action.

So I did something like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="RoleB,RoleC")]
public ActionResult MyAction(){
  //irrelevant
}
```

But, the `CustomAuthorize` action filter is never hit, when `[AllowAnonymous]` is present.

So does `[AllowAnonymous]` override `[CustomAuthorize]`?

Comment: So, how do you intend to prevent a user in RoleA from logging out and becoming anonymous, so that they can access this action?

Comment: Show your `CustomAuthorize` class.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I understand this. There was a bug raised by an internal tester that is making me do this.

Comment: I still don't understand. It's like giving a security guard a picture of someone to keep out, but then emphasizing to that guard "this person never wears sunglasses, so if you see someone wearing sunglasses, you can safely let them in" - what possible security benefit have you achieved?

Comment: Security none, business purpose yes. The action actually opens a corresponding view from which you can make calls to set of fixed numbers. As in `RoleA`, the person is disallowed to make calls as the call will actually land to himself.

Comment: @Aniket That doesn't sound like something the security framework should enforce.

Answer (score 10):

To answer the question as asked (a little late, but hey might be useful for someone):

AllowAnonymous has the following description:

> Represents an attribute that marks controllers and actions to skip the
>   AuthorizeAttribute during authorization.

Thus adding this along with an authorize attribute will result in the authorization code not running at all.

This also has the effect that if you add this as an attribute on your controller as a whole (i.e. at class level), then adding individual Authorize attributes to actions on that controller will have no effect.

Comment: I found this to be absolutely true... class level AllowAnoymous overrides method level Authorize

Comment: I just implemented both [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] on a number of endpoints, because there's an important caveat: the method will allow anonymous access, but if the request contains valid credentials (in my case a bearer token), the user will be authenticated. This means that you can retrieve the user id and eg. personalize the output (my usecase).

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy to achieve.

Remove the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and use your custom authorize attribute:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult MyAction(){
  //irrelevant
}
```

and in your CustomAuthorize filter check if user belongs to 'RoleA', if yes then restrict access else allow access.

Answer (score 1):

A foolproof approach would be to code your own attribute and inherit it from the `AuthorizeAttribute`. The implementation is trivial.

```
public class RestrictRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public RestrictRoleAttribute()
        {

        }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            string[] roles = Roles.Split(',');

            // Test if current user belongs into restricted role
            foreach (string r in roles)
            {
                if (httpContext.User.IsInRole(r))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
[RestrictRole(Roles="RoleB,RoleC")]
public ActionResult MyAction(){
  //irrelevant
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but it might be the case. If you think about [Authorize] attribute which is on the controller level then the [AllowAnonymous] will override it so it takes a precedence over it.

Could you try to swap them with places so that [CustomAuthorize] will be on the top to see the result?

Regards

Comment: now it lets everyone in.. cannot restrict it to one particular role type

Comment: What if you would just in your custom validator do the check if user is anonymous? This way you could remove the [AllowAnonymous] and just check there if user is anonymous and let him perform the action?

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up writing a deny attribute:

```
public class DenyUserAttribute : CustomAuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```